# jQuery .load() won't load data into <form></form>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have HTML like so:

```
<form>
<div id="to_receive_data">
</div>
</form>
```

Javascript like so:

```
$("#to_receive_data").load("./loadable/a_form_to_load.php");
```

When the .load() completes, the DOM shows:

```
<form>
</form>
<div id="to_receive_data">
<input name="data_from_ajax" value"help_i_need_a_form"/>
</div>
```

As you can see, the div was moved outside of the  element.

When I press submit, the action page receives no parameters. Is there a .load() quirk here that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Try removing `./` from the url.

Comment: What does `a_form_to_load.php` output? just 
`<input name="data_from_ajax" value"help_i_need_a_form"/>`? It should be related to the invalid markup.

Comment: With this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G2Cz6/ It appears that it shouldn't be an issue. I suspect it's what @undefined suggested, that your markup that's returned is invalid and breaking out of the `form` element. I've seen this before, and I think this is what it came down to.

Comment: Just to make sure you're tracking, that .php isn't going to execute. If you're loading it with jQuery, unless you're trying to load the content of the file as text into the div. PHP executes on the server side before the page gets sent to the browser.

Comment: @Peter: the server executes the php script when the ajax request is made.

Comment: @JaredFarrish, undefined: My initial inclination was that the data is invalid and I suspect you're probably right.

Comment: Update: The markup on the _calling_ page was invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You assuming the data you are receiving is valid, you could try something like this and bypass the load method.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "form.php",
    dataType: "text",
    type: "GET",
    success: function (data){
         //manually insert the page
         $("#to_receive_data").html(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

.load() method load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element. There are functions which support similar functionality like .load(). Please refer the following functions.

- $.ajax
- $.post
- $.get

You can use the either of above functions.

Please refer the following example for the implementation.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: './loadable/a_form_to_load.php',
  data: data,
  dataType: dataType,
  success: function (data){
     $("#to_receive_data").html(data);
  }
});
```

Else if you want a more simplified version try this too.

```
$.post('./loadable/a_form_to_load.php', function(data) {
  $("#to_receive_data").html(data);
});
```

Hope this will help you out. If you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask. Thanks